# Craft an IP in IP example with scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am trying to send an IP in IP packet with scapy but I seem to be missing or misunderstanding something. Here is my attempt:

```
from scapy.all import *

payload = "HelloWorld" 
inner = IP(dst="192.168.1.2")
inner.add_payload(payload)
outer = IP(dst="192.168.1.2")
send(outer/inner)
```

I watched for the packet with wireshark on the destination and it showed that the packet was malformed:

> Expert Info (Error/Protocol): IPv6 Hop-by-Hop extension header must
> appear immediately after IPv6 header

the destination then sends an ICMP packet back with type 3 (destination unreachable) and code 2 (Protocol unreachable).

I have tried setting several protocols on the outer and inner packets (protocol 4 IPv4 encapsulation feels right) but so far they all send back a "protocol unreachable" ICMP packet.

If it makes a difference my intent is to have the inner packet get sent to a different destination than the outer packet. I just thought I should make the simplest possible example to get started. Once I figure out why I am getting a protocol unreachable message I will change the inner packets destination IP.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an IP in IP packet (Outer IP header, Inner IP header, IP payload), e.g.:

```
from scapy.all import *

payload = "TEST"
send(IP(dst="192.168.1.2")/IP(dst="192.168.1.2")/UDP(dport=4444)/payload)
```

Comment: IP encapsulation IS a thing. See the RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2003 (although is that really what the op wants here? who knows...)

Comment: I think he just wants to send an IP address... But yes, it is difficult to understand what OP wants.  :/

Comment: @Cukic0d Sorry if I am using incorrect terminology I am very new to this. What is vague about that part of my question? I said I wanted an IP in IP packet which is what this type of encapsulation is called on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_in_IP

Comment: I have updated the answer, It is an IP tunnel; like IP in IP. Does it work for you?